# Cannot submit form after correcting error

Tags: javascript, html

When I hit the generate entry button the form with an error (for example click only option one), the alert pops up. I correctly check all three checkboxes and then when I hit Generate Entry again the page does nothing. I want to be able to make the correction without reloading the page and then hit the button the form.

After button click, the page generates a new window with the information from the form inside an editable textarea.

HTML:

```
<body>
<form id="templateForm">
        <div class="inputSection">
            <input type="checkbox" id="option1">Option 1</option><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option2">Option 2</option><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option3">Option 3</option><br>
        </div>
<input type="button" value="Generate Entry" onclick="submitButtonClicked()">
</form>
</body>
```

```
function submitButtonClicked(){
    if (document.getElementById("option1").checked && document.getElementById("option2").checked && document.getElementById("option3").checked){
        let option1 = "Option 1";
        let option2 = "Option 2";
        let option3 = "Option 3";
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert("All three options must be checked!");
        return false;
    }


    var win = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=780,height=200,top="+(screen.height-400)+",left="+(screen.width-840));
    win.document.body.innerHTML = "<form>" + "<textarea style='width:85%; height:85%'>" + 
    option1 + option2 + option3 + "</textarea>" + "<form>";
}
```

Comment: _"...and then when I hit Submit again the page does nothing"_. Why should it? `submitButtonClicked()` doesn't submit the form. And because the button is just a `type="button"` it doesn't submit the form either.

Comment: I guess I am not submitting anything, I am just wanting the page to generate the new window and populate it with the data. Edited question to reflect that

Comment: @sosCoder47 Do you want the data to open in a new tab, modal or alert?

Comment: new window. so modal i think

Comment: @sosCoder47 Have you actually tried? If so, please can you add the code you have tried. If not, please try yourself and come back if you have any issues.

Comment: the code above is what i am using

Answer (score 0):

remove the `return true;` from first conditional statement, when you put return true it won't continue and the function will only return 1

so if you want to generate a new page on every input is checked use this block code (it's better) :

```
function submitButtonClicked(){
if (!document.getElementById("option1").checked || 
!document.getElementById("option2").checked || 
!document.getElementById("option3").checked){

alert("All three options must be checked!");
    return false;
}

    let option1 = "Option 1";
    let option2 = "Option 2";
    let option3 = "Option 3";

var win = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=780,height=200,top="+(screen.height-400)+",left="+(screen.width-840));
win.document.body.innerHTML = "<form>" + "<textarea style='width:85%; height:85%'>" + 
option1 + option2 + option3 + "</textarea>" + "<form>";
```

}

Comment: Your welcome! If your problem solved please close this and vote!